# Windows 10 upgrade report - vmware svga 3d not supported

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10, vmware-fusion

I have an `Windows 8.1` vm, running under fusion. The `Windows 10` upgrade tool says that the SVGA 3D driver is not supported. 
I check all settings for the display and don't nothing i can change or a way to replace the display hardware. VM tools are installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The report is invalid, it is simple a bug on the tool, so the solution is to download the iso and install it from cd-rom.
All steps [here](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2126929).

Comment: It is already there. Check "here", a post from VM forum.

Answer (score 1):

1. Uninstall VMware tools
2. Shut down VM
3. Change VM settings to Windows 10
4. Restart Windows
5. Delete all files in
   c:\windows\softwaredistribution\download
6. Run wuauclt.exe /updatenow
   from CMD as Administrator
7. Go to Windows Update and Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: 
Device Manager/Display Adapters/VMware SVGA 3D - right click and choose Update Driver Software
Choose 'Browse my computer' and Let me pick from a list of device drivers.
Choose Microsoft Basic Display Adapter.

run in admin command prompt: 
schtasks.exe /Run /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience\Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser"

wait a little while for the windows 10 update to refresh (and restart probably)

Answer (score 0):

actually had this problem on an upgrade from 2012 server core to 2016 server core. When you go into the panther directory (c:\windows~BT/soruces/Panther) you will find an HTML file where it displays this. I guess server core does not have the ability to display html files.

Anyways it was fixed by re running setup.exe as "**setup.exe /compat ignorewarning**", after mounting the datastore ISO of server 2016. This allows the install to complete in my case and bypass the vmware error.